# Wpf Datagrid scroll at top and Unselect all in grouping by default

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am developing a wpf Image gallery.what I want to do is that when user scrolls all the way to top.More Images are fetched from database. I am unable to find a scroll event for datagrid?.Secondly I have used grouping feature of datagrid but it is always scrolled at top and first item is selected by default.Is there a way to unselect all by default and to put scroll bar at bottom?.Thanks in advance

Comment: describe your first part of question

Comment: @safi I want to know scroll event of datagrid which can notify me when users scroll bar is at top of grid

Comment: it's by default on top, or do you want it when the user come down and back to top?

Comment: @safi I am using grouping feature of datagrid.So what's happening is that the scroll bar is at top by default and fist item is selected.That is not what I want.I want the scroll bar to be at the bottom of datagrid.Secondly when user scrolls back all the way to top it should notify me so that I can fetch some more Images from database

Answer (score 1):

you should first get the scrollViewer and then you need the `ScrollChanged` Event this describe how

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(dgFamily);
    if (scrollViewer != null)
        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += scrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
}
void scrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VerticalOffset == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("You reach to top");
}
private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);

    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```